# How to make text green if chinese words are equals?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning Android Studio and I have a question: I wanna say something in chinese and there compare the word/phrase I said with the one that was displayed at the screen. And if these two words are equals - make text green. else - red. But it always red after I press the mic button.
Will appriciate any help

```
public class SpeakingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 1000;
TextView mTextView;
TextView input;
ImageButton mImageButton;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.speakingfromhome);
    button = findViewById(R.id.nextSpeaking);
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.output);
    mImageButton = findViewById(R.id.image);
    input = findViewById(R.id.input);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeQuestions();
            mTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
    mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speak();
            checkIfCorrect();
        }

    });
}


private void checkIfCorrect() {
    if (input.toString().equals(mTextView.toString()))
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    else
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}

private void changeQuestions() {
    input.setText("基辅");
}

private void speak() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.CHINA.toString());
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                mTextView.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, start debugging it then: print out the values you're comparing, and see if they look like what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function checkIfCorrect() is the problem

Change it to:

- `input.toString()` -> `input.getText()`
- `mTextView.toString()` -> `mTextView.getText()`

Like:

```
input.getText().equals(mTextView.getText())
```

with `getText()` get the text of the TextView, doint `input.toString()` convert the object TextView to String

your checkIfCorrect function must look like:

```
private void checkIfCorrect() {
    if (input.getText().equals(mTextView.getText()))
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    else
        mTextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

A better way:

```
private void checkIfCorrect() {
  mTextView.setTextColor((input.getText().equals(mTextView.getText())) ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED )
}
```